# QWidget::render() crash

Tags: c++, qt

I have a big QWidget(w_mapa) with a lot of QPushButton and I get a jpg picture from it with this code

```
QRect rectangle=ui->w_mapa->rect();
QPixmap pixmap(rectangle.size());
ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(rectangle));
QString nombre_fichero=QString("x%1.jpg").arg(tam_castillos);
pixmap.save(nombre_fichero);
```

This code works, but if the number of QPushButton is bigger the program crash and the debugger show me sigsegv segmentation fault in a QList.

then I try get the jpg in 4 parts with this code:

```
QRect rectangle=ui->w_mapa->rect();
QRect uno,dos,tres,cuatro;
uno=QRect(rectangle.x(),rectangle.y(),rectangle.width()/2,rectangle.height()/2);
dos=QRect(rectangle.x()+rectangle.width()/2,rectangle.y(),rectangle.width()/2,rectangle.height()/2);
tres=QRect(rectangle.x(),rectangle.y()+rectangle.height()/2,rectangle.width()/2,rectangle.height()/2);
cuatro=QRect(rectangle.x()+rectangle.width()/2,rectangle.y()+rectangle.height()/2,
                     rectangle.width()/2,rectangle.height()/2);

QPixmap pixmap(uno.size());
ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(uno));
QString nombre_fichero=QString("x%1uno.jpg").arg(tam_castillos);
pixmap.save(nombre_fichero);

pixmap=QPixmap(dos.size());
ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(dos));
nombre_fichero=QString("x%1dos.jpg").arg(tam_castillos);
pixmap.save(nombre_fichero);

pixmap=QPixmap(tres.size());
ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(tres));
nombre_fichero=QString("x%1tres.jpg").arg(tam_castillos);
pixmap.save(nombre_fichero);

pixmap=QPixmap(cuatro.size());
ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(cuatro));
nombre_fichero=QString("x%1cuatro.jpg").arg(tam_castillos);
pixmap.save(nombre_fichero);
```

this code works and i get 4 jpg files but I need generate 1.

I am searching info about this error without success

can I fuse 4 jpg files in 1? or solve this error?

And sorry for my english, I am learning.

**CODE DETAILS:**
MainWindow.h

```
...
private:
QList<QPushButton*> buttons;
...
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
...
void MainWindow::showMap(){

    for(int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++)
        delete buttons.at(i);
    buttons.clear();
    QList<coordinates> coordinates;//external data from request
    //coordinates have x position, y position and name
    for(int i=0;i<coordinates.size();i++)
    {
        QPushButton *aux=new QPushButton(ui->w_mapa);
        aux->setName(coordinates.name);
        aux->move(coordinates.x,coordinates.y);
        buttons.append(aux);
    }
    QPixmap pixmap(ui->w_mapa.size());
    ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap);
    QString nombre_fichero="x1.jpg";
    pixmap.save(nombre_fichero);
}
```

---

**RESOLVED:**
I didn't fix the crash but I separate the QWidget::render() in two Pixmaps and then merge this Pixmaps.

```
QRect rectangle=ui->w_mapa->rect();
QRect unoydos,tresycuatro;
QPixmap all(rectangle.size());
QPainter painter(&all);
unoydos=QRect(rectangle.x(),rectangle.y(),rectangle.width(),rectangle.height()/2);
tresycuatro=QRect(rectangle.x(),rectangle.y()+rectangle.height()/2,rectangle.width(),rectangle.height()/2);

QPixmap pixmap(unoydos.size());
ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(unoydos));
painter.drawPixmap(0,0,unoydos.width(),unoydos.height(),pixmap);

pixmap=QPixmap(tresycuatro.size());
ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(tresycuatro));
painter.drawPixmap(0,unoydos.height(),tresycuatro.width(),tresycuatro.height(),pixmap);

all.save(QString("x%1.jpg").arg(tam_castillos));
```

Comment: Do you really need `rect()`? I would use it as `QPixmap pixmap(ui->w_mapa->size()); ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap);`. However, it should not crash. Which line crashes? Put some debug output between lines. How do you call that code (slot, event,...)? What is backtrace?

Comment: sigsegv error in `ui->w_mapa->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(rectangle));` with or without `rect()`. The code is into QPushButton clicked slot and the QPushButtons of the widget are into QList<QPushButton*>

Comment: The solution with rendering by parts may be unstable, since the root cause of the crash is not in window size or number of buttons. It is possible that there is some memory corruption before. It is strange that the crash is somehow related to `QList`, since the rendering code should not touch your private `QList`. If you want to find the problem give some more code of your objects.

Comment: ok, i edited with the code brief, the code is so long but in esence is something like it